# How to place image & textfiled both at center in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How to place image & textfield both at center in flutter.

Below is code what i have tried so far any help is appreciated!

```
Container(
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Container(
          child: Image.asset(
            'images/Warning.png',
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
          child: Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Text(
              'OTP is valid for 5 minutes only.',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                fontSize: 12,
                fontFamily: 'Soleil_Regular',
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
),
```

trying as some thing shown in the picture both text & image is in same line any help is appreciated!

Comment: Center on screen?

Comment: both text & image should be in same line like in android adding drawable start to textfield

Comment: Will it  be look like attached image?

Comment: yes as above attached img

Comment: So there will be image then Text on a single Row?

Comment: yes there will be image then Text on a single Row

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239947/discussion-between-hemavathi-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way of doing it by using [`RichText`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

```dart
     RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: TextSpan(children: [
                WidgetSpan(child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit)), // use image in your case instead of icon
                TextSpan(text: "This is Text")
              ]))
```

**Full Snippet**

```dart
     Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
                  child: Text.rich(TextSpan(
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontFamily: 'Soleil_Regular'),
                    children: [
                      WidgetSpan(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'images/Warning.png',
                          alignment: Alignment.center,
                        ),
                      ),
                      WidgetSpan(
                          child: SizedBox(
                        width: 10,
                      )),
                      TextSpan(
                        text: 'OTP is valid for 5 minutes only.',
                      ),
                    ],
                  )),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  RichText(
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      text: TextSpan(children: [
                        WidgetSpan(
                            child: Icon(Icons
                                .ac_unit)), // use image in your case instead of icon
                        TextSpan(text: "This is Text")  ]))] ), ), ),

Comment: only image is getting shown text is not visible in ui

Comment: you dont need to use `row`

Comment: not required, i need to add some space in between image & text also

Comment: in flutter font size is taken in pixel?

Comment: wrap with padding on `Icon`, in your case `image`

Comment: Another `WidgetSpan` with `SizedBox` works better in this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239948/discussion-between-hemavathi-and-yeasin-sheikh).

Answer (score 0):

Give your image a size and you will get your result

```
Container(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 32.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Image.network(
                      'http://orbitsystemsinc.com/images/banner-round-bg.png',width: 40,height: 40,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text(
                        'OTP is valid for 5 minutes only.',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFF4B4B4B),
                          fontSize: 12,
                          fontFamily: 'Soleil_Regular',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
```

[image]